# weblogic cert validation

Tags: certificate, weblogic

How do I validate whether a Weblogic certificate is valid or not?

Comment: And what is a non valid certificate for you (which is not weblogic specific btw)?

Answer (score 0):

Figure out the location of the keystore / truststore from the console and use the keytool command to list all the certs present. If you use the verbose flag for the listing, you will see their expiration dates.

Also, if it's a webapp and you're using an expired cert for SSL, you will get a warning when you attempt to access the URL from a browser.